# I have Windows Form App which utilizes SQL Server Database and SSRS report. which files are necessary for stand alone run?

Tags: sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

Is there a way in Visual Studio to check dependencies such as a database or report?  They are on my local computer now, but I want to send them to a peer to have it tested.  I have a dbo file which looks like my database.  I also have an rdl file which looks like the actual report.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS runs on a host of SQL Server instance. The report is delivered either in a browser or in a control you can embed in a Windows form or WPF form.

On a standalone, development machine,  you would have to install SQL Server (developer version is very cheap and very powerful) and install SSRS along with the instance.